# Finding type signatures in Haskell that are too specific

Tags: haskell

Is there some automated tool that will find type signatures in my code that are too specific? For a contrived example let's say I write

```
add3 :: Int -> Int
add3 = (+ 3)
```

Is there some program I could run (say, "checkSingatures foo.hs") that would tell me that I could have written

```
add3 :: Num a => a -> a
add3 = (+ 3)
```

I wouldn't think this would be too hard--strip out the type signatures and see what GHCi infers.

Comment: You already gave the answer in the question: strip the signature and let GHCi infer it.

Comment: Why do want to do that in the first place? Specific types often result in more optimized code and there is `specialize` pragma if you want to specialize the general type to some specific one so that compiler can optimize that particular instance of the function.

Comment: @MihaiMaruseac - I said "automated tool"; manually stripping signatures doesn't scale.

Comment: @Satvik for the learning experience, sort of the same reason one uses hlint. Sometimes I'll see "oh, really this code is more general than I thought." Also I often find that more general type signatures with type variables are easier to understand, as overarching patterns can be more obvious. The things I do are seldom performance sensitive.

Comment: Don't write them in the first place. Unless the functions are top-level. It will suddenly scale.

Answer (score 2):

While I am not directly aware of such a tool, it would be maybe something interesting to have (and maybe you could suggest this to the `hlint` maintainer as an addition). But to your question I can at least give you a "starting point", actually a shell script, that could help you a bit.

```
#!/bin/sh

sourceFile=$1
tempFile="`mktemp`.hs"

originalTypes=`mktemp`
inferedTypes=`mktemp`

ghc -fno-code -fforce-recomp -ddump-types $sourceFile 2>&1 | sed -n '/^TYPE/,/^TYPE/{/^TYPE/!p}' > $originalTypes
cat $sourceFile | grep -P -v "\s+.*?\s+::" > $tempFile
ghc -fno-code -fforce-recomp -ddump-types $tempFile 2>&1 | sed -n '/^TYPE/,/^TYPE/{/^TYPE/!p}' > $inferedTypes

diff $originalTypes $inferedTypes
```

Of course it doesn't handle well multiline definitions (and maybe many other cases), but it shows you that you can get in a scriptable fashion the inferred types via the `-ddump-types` directive.